# Pronunciation of a made up company name called 'logeek' with domain 'logeek.ly'

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

I wanted to ask how native speakers find this made up company name, is it conveying any message to you? I wanted to merge words 'logically' and 'geek' into one. I wonder if you, as native speakers, find this neologism 'logeekly' pronounceable, friendly and self-explanatory?

I'm aware that it is not the most appropriate site for this question, but I could't find a better one.

Comment: I read it as "log - eek - ly" and had no idea what it was meant to be!  Personally, I think it's horrible.  Anyway, what does "logically geek" mean?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. How do you find name 'logeek'? It is supposed to be a name for coding school, result of merging logic and geek. http://www.meetup.com/Become-a-Java-programmer-in-Wimbledon-Logeek/ I want to register a company that's why I want to make sure native speakers do not find it horrible like you do.

Comment: Well on the linked website the logo clearly puts the break as LO-GEEK.  One problem with combining words or parts thereof is that different people may see them in different ways, like I say LOG-EEK.  Anyway, I always think of 'geek' as a somewhat derogatory term, so I wouldn't want to use it!

Comment: It would tend to be pronounced as either "log-eek", "lo-geek", or "logic" ("loj-eek").  There would be confusion as to which to use.

Comment: I understand it is logic but it feels a little difficult to figure out. Although geek is plainly visible, only lo seems a little odd. Difficult words to combine.  Something like logi-geek sounds cute but this time it doesn't  really combine.

Comment: "Logik" would have the same pronunciation as *logic*, but you lose the play on words. The problem is that the the letter G in *geek* has a different pronunciation from *logic*. You could use **lojeek** (the "g" has the same pronunciation as in *logic*)  but would people get the *geek* reference?

Answer (score 1):

logeek.

US native.  I hear it as "low geek."  That kind of sounds like even less than a geek.  Not like "low fat greek yogurt," but a kind of "undergeek," if you will.  I'm imagining a geek who is kind of cast out from the other geeks.  He only gets called for Dungeons and Dragons if literally everyone else is out of town or sick.

The idea of logic is lost.  Only sadness.

Comment: Thanks :) Looks like I need to come up with a different name.